# Downloading from ftp to local daily

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm working on a C#/SqlServer/batch project, and one of the numerous part is that everyday when I come to work I have to download manually from a ftp server on filezilla `csv` and `xml` files that I need to transform with the `exe` i'm actually working on.

My question is simple: How could I, in `C#`, download  the new folders that are added everyday at 9:00 AM, and make them go on my local Drive, so I could make my work more automatic, and if possible respecting the file/folder tree. I need this because when my app will be used on live servers I will need to download automatically everyday.

Comment: _How could I, in C# …_ - you would write code to do so?! Stack Overflow is not a code writing service - there are numerous examples on the web on downloading files with FTP. You need to **try it for yourself** - if you get stuck, by all means come back and ask a _specific_ question.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you have a look at NuGet for a suitable FTP library (eg: [Ftp.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ftp.dll/)), rather than trying to roll your own, and use that to query and download from your FTP server.

How you then trigger this code is up to you - the quick and dirty solution is a console app launched by Task Scheduler on your machine or a shortcut in your StartUp folder. Alternatively you can go with the SledgeHammer approach and write a windows service using something like [FluentScheduler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentScheduler/) to schedule the downloads.